# C# - Getting List<byte> reference index

Tags: linq, list, object, reference, compare

I have a List>

```
List<List<Byte>> bytes = new List<List<Byte>>()
{
 new List<Byte> {1, 1, 2, 3, 4}, // index 0 is original
 new List<Byte> {0, 0, 2, 4, 1},
 new List<Byte> {1, 2, 2, 1, 1},
 new List<Byte> {1, 0, 2, 2, 2}
};
```

and the first List is original. Then I sort my List, and I have to find my original List index.

```
bytes:
[0] = {0, 0, 2, 4, 1}
[1] = {1, 0, 2, 2, 2}
[2] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4}  // here is that index
[3] = {1, 2, 2, 1, 1}
```

One guy suggested me to use reference on first not sorted List then sort List and use ReferenceEqual, but this doesn't work for me. Am I doing something wrong by setting reference or it doesn't work on List? How could I get the index of original in sorted array? P.S I'm sorting with OrderBy and IComparer.

This is how I try to make reference:

```
List<byte> reference = new List<byte>(bytes[0]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is how I try to make reference:
>
> ```
> List<byte> reference = new List<byte>(bytes[0]);
> ```

That's not the right way to make a reference, because you make a copy by calling a constructor of `List<byte>`. The copy of `bytes[0]` is not present in `bytes`, so you wouldn't be able to find it by checking reference equality.

This is how you should do it:

```
List<byte> reference = bytes[0];
```

Now `reference` references the list that is at position zero before sorting, so you should be able to find its index by using reference equality.

Comment: You were right, the reason I tried that, cause I saw somewhere how it is done with objects, I thought that with lists will be the same way. Thank you very much for fast and correct answer! :)